# MARS MIPS Bit Shifting using SRA

Tags: assembly, mips, bit-shift, twos-complement

So when shifting -34 by 2 bits using SRA, I get an output of -9 using the code below. I can not figure out why it is giving me -9 and not another number

```
addi $t0, $zero, -34
sra $s0, $t0, 2
addi $v0, $zero, 4
la $a0, result1
syscall
addi $v0, $zero, 1
move $a0, $s0
syscall
```

Comment: floor(-34/4) is -9.  Arithmetic right shift rounds towards -inf.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which kind of signed integer division corresponds to bit shift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63018450/which-kind-of-signed-integer-division-corresponds-to-bit-shift)

Answer (score 1):

-34 in (two's complement) binary is:

```
11111111 11111111 11111111 11011110
^                                 ^
bit 31                            bit 0
```

Shift that arithmetically 2 bits to the right and you get:

```
11111111 11111111 11111111 11110111
```

Which is -9