# Which kind of signed integer division corresponds to bit shift?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bit-shift, integer-division

It is a familiar fact that when dividing integers by a power of two, a good compiler will strength-reduce this to bit shift.

For example:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    return argc/2;
}
```

Clang -O2 compiles this to:

```
movl    %ecx, %eax
shrl    $31, %eax
addl    %ecx, %eax
sarl    %eax
retq
```

It is worth noting that while this sequence of instructions is much faster than an actual divide instruction, it is *not* just a single bit shift as one would hope. Presumably that is because typical CPUs, along with C, ended up settling on truncating division (quotient rounds towards zero), and this happens not to exactly match arithmetic right shift (and the strength reduction is required to exactly preserve the semantics).

Which flavor of signed integer division *would* exactly match arithmetic right shift?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In case **arithmetic** shift right is performed, `floor` by power of 2 is the best suitable operation which matches signed integer shift right (rounding toward *-inf*).

Note that shift right of signed integer is implementation defined. It may be either **arithmetic** shift right (implemented by most of the well known compilers) or **logical** shift right. More about the difference between those two operations can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44694957/5218277).

Example with arithmetic shift right: https://godbolt.org/z/zhhfbc

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void)
{
    int val1 = 7;
    int val2 = -7;
    
    printf("Value1 = %.1lf\n", floor(val1/2.0));
    printf("Value2 = %.1lf\n", floor(val2/2.0));

    printf("Value1 = %d\n", val1 >> 1);
    printf("Value2 = %d\n", val2 >> 1);  

    return 0;
}
```

And the output is:

```
Value1 = 3.0

Value2 = -4.0

Value1 = 3

Value2 = -4
```

Comment: In other words, rounding toward minus infinity.

Comment: @NateEldredge Probably rounding down to nearest integer would be a better wording.

Comment: @AlexLop. no the correct term is rounding toward -inf https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754#Directed_roundings, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_shift#Non-equivalence_of_arithmetic_right_shift_and_division